# ESP32 not recognising that any device is connected to its access point

Tags: c++, arduino, esp32

I have gotten my ESP32 to create a wireless access point. It shows up fine on any device however, no matter what device I try and connect (iPhone 6s, iPhone 8, Windows desktop), the ESP32 just says that there is no device connected.
My code is:

```cpp
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <WiFiAP.h>

const char *ssid = "testAP";
const char *password = "0000000000";

WiFiServer server(48899);


void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(5000);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Configuring access point...");

  WiFi.softAP(ssid, password);
  IPAddress myIP = WiFi.softAPIP();
  Serial.print("AP IP address: ");
  Serial.println(myIP);
  server.begin();

  Serial.println("Server started");
}

void loop() {
  WiFiClient client = server.available();   // listen for incoming clients

  if (client) {
    Serial.println(client);// if you get a client,
    Serial.println("New Client.");           // print a message out the serial port
    String currentLine = "";                // make a String to hold incoming data from the client
    while (client.connected()) {            // loop while the client's connected
      if (client.available()) {             // if there's bytes to read from the client,
        char c = client.read();             // read a byte, then
        //Serial.write(c);                    // print it out the serial monitor
      }
    }
  }
  // close the connection:
  //client.stop();
  Serial.println(client); //this will print "0" no matter how many clients are connected

  }
```

Right now, it will print '0' over and over again since that is the number of clients connected. If I connect a device, it should increase to 1 however it doesn't.

With just the default installation of the ESP32 board (from the boards manager) on verbose output the "error" I get is:

> dhcps: send_offer>>udp_sendto result 0

Googling this brings up quite a few issues on this, mainly mentioning [this](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/issues/2285) github issue. The issue was opened all the way back in 7th Jan 2019. It's latest response was a few weeks ago. To this day, there hasn't been a fix posted. A lot of people say updating to the latest ESP32 release from github (not boards manager) will work, so I tried it.
I removed the one from the boards manager and installed the latest github release. It no longer gives me the 'dhcps: send_offer>>udp_sendto result 0' message even on verbose output, but it still doesn't recognise that any device is connected.

In my code, I have tried using the Arduino library version:
`#include <Wifi.h>`
and also the ESP library version:
`#include "Wifi.h"`
No luck there either.

Could anyone point me in the right direction on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how this works. Your program is working properly; your expectations are wrong.

`WiFiServer` is poorly named. It has nothing to do with clients connecting to the wifi network that `softAP` creates. Instead it creates a server listening on the TCP port number that you gave it when you created the object (in this case, 48899). It should really be called `TCPServer` but sadly, it's not, and we all just have to live with it.

> If I connect a device, it should increase to 1 however it doesn't.

This is incorrect. If you connect a device to the wifi network it's not the same thing as connecting to a `WiFiServer`.

For your code to work, each device that connects to the wifi network your ESP32 is providing **will also** have to be run a program on it that opens a TCP connection to port 48899 on the ESP32. Otherwise the loop will never see a client available because there will be none.

If you want to know whether any devices have connected to the WiFi access point, you can use `WiFi.softAPgetStationNum()` - it will return the number of currently connected devices.

For instance,

```
Serial.println(WiFi.softAPgetStationNum());
```

will print how many devices are connected.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. I got the code from the ESP32 wifi access point example. That explains why there's a lot of extra code in the while loop. Is it possible to get around this? I just need to be able to know whether a device has connected to the access point. I don't need any specific details like the IP of the device, just whether one is connected.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how to see how many devices are connected to the wifi softAP.